# Why is there no Dictionary.TrimExcess()?

Tags: .net, collections, dictionary

In .NET, there is a constructor for `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` that takes one parameter, `int capacity`. This is the same as with many other collections such as `List<T>`, `Queue<T>`, and `Stack<T>`; furthermore, according to [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk84bxf4%28VS.80%29.aspx):

> The capacity of a Dictionary is the number of elements that can be added to the Dictionary before resizing is necessary. As elements are added to a Dictionary, the capacity is automatically increased as required by reallocating the internal array.

This sounds to me pretty much the same as with other collections like `List<T>`, etc. Since these collections feature auto-resizing behavior when necessary and are therefore likely to have a greater capacity than required, most of them feature a `TrimExcess` method. This is handy if, say, you are adding an unknown number of items to the collection at one time, and after that you won't be adding any additional items.

Why does `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` not have this same `TrimExcess` method?

(Disclaimer: I'm quite familiar with the "features do not exist by default" response; I guess I'm mostly just wondering if there's a particular reason why `TrimExcess` for a `Dictionary` does not make sense, or why it would be significantly more difficult to implement than for simpler collections like `List`.)

Comment: Since `HashSet` has a `TrimExcess` method and also works with a HashTable internally, I think there is no technical reason for not implementing `TrimExcess` for `Dictionary`. They even say in the documentation that a `HashSet` is like a `Dictionary` without values.

Comment: seems to be related to implementation because .NET Core 2.1 has TrimExcess() https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trimexcess

Comment: I *assume* Microsoft intentionally didn't add a `TrimExcess` method to `Dictionary<K,V>`   when it debuted in .NET Framework 2.0 because .NET Framework 1.1's `System.Collections.Hashtable` doesn't have a similar method either. Resizing a `List<T>`/`vector<T>` or `T[]` array is trivial (as existing item indexes remain constant, so a simple allocate-and-copy works fine), but resizing a hashtable is more difficult as actual hash-keys need to be recomputed based on the load-factor. Growing a hashtable's internal bucket array is much safer than shrinking it (due to collision-resolution).

Comment: ...so I'm thinking that Microsoft *intended* developers to "shrink" a `Dictionary<K,V>` by replacing-and-repopulating the entire `Dictionary` object rather than allowing the bucket-array to be resized internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per MSDN Dictionary is implemented as a hash table.  If you trimmed excess you would have to come up with an algorithm that still provided close to O(1) lookup times in what would effectively be a randomly sorted list.

Comment: What does O(1) lookup have to the with TrimExess?  HashSet.TrimExess in O(n).

Answer (score 7):

By 2019, .Net Standard 2.1+ and .Net Core 2.1+ implement `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.TrimExcess()`:

see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trimexcess?view=netstandard-2.1

.Net Framework doesn't implement it in any version.

Answer (score 6):

I'd guess that in this case the capacity argument helps define the hashing function as well as the number of buckets; resizing/trimming a sparse collection of data would require recalculating hashes of all of the stored items remaining.

Comment: Actually, they use the hashcode of the Key object through `GetHashCode()` and remove the most significant bit. Then they store it in a location in the array by the remainder of `length % hash` (until a free one is found). Of course, the calculation of the hashcodes is key-class dependent.

Comment: In more technical detail, Dictionary chooses which bucket to place an item using "buckets[key.getHashCode() % buckets.Length] = value". Changing the length of the bucket list requires moving all values to new buckets.

Comment: @Juliet: almost. The bucket is resized when needed and the whole list of entries is copied in the process and indexes are recalculated and thus the objects repositioned.

Answer (score 5):

This is partially a guess: a Dictionary is "ordered" as a hash table. The capacity that is reserved, is not simply a bunch of free memory addresses on top of your Dictionary. Instead, it consists of empty room throughout the Dictionary. This is done to make adding / moving / removing etc very efficient. If you had a `TrimExcess` method for Dictionary, the whole Dictionary would have to copy everything to a new location without any gaps between the elements.

Actually: the gaps should remain otherwise the benefit of a hash table becomes void, trimming (`TrimExcess`), if implemented, should only trim the internal `ValueCollection`.

**Update:** expanded and changed my ill-chosen words
**Update:** [the BCL team says TrimExcess for Dictionaries "could be useful"](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/418546/implement-trimexcess-for-dictionaries).
**Update:** the feature request resolved as *Won't Fix*: "Unfortunately, we won't be able to get to this for the next release of .NET, so I'm resolving this as Won't Fix."

Comment: Dictionary is not ordered - it is implemented as a hash table. The ordered equivalent is SortedDictionary.

Comment: I know, it is not ordered in that way, it is ordered as a hash. Sorry if that wasn't clear

Answer (score 1):

Actually I was the one that asked Microsoft to implement TrimExcess.
I already presented more than one article that deals with dictionaries and in all cases I implemented TrimExcess. In fact, the Resize used when the buckets are too small can be invoked when increasing or decreasing the size of the buckets.

Today I just published another article, it is a C++ implementation of a dictionary, which supports TrimExcess:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/761040/A-NET-like-Dictionary-in-Cplusplus

Another implementation (.NET) can be found in this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/548406/Dictionary-plus-Locking-versus-ConcurrentDictionar